# laravel ajax filter published by radio

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, filter

I'm trying to make an Ajax post filter with radio buttons. So that the user can filter through two published products using the radio buttons.

This is the code I used:

**category.blade.php**

```
<div class="card mb-3">
    <div class="card-header">{{ __('Published') }}</div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input published_filter" type="radio" name="published" id="yes">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="yes">
                Yes
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input published_filter" type="radio" name="published" id="no">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="no">
                No
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
$(".published_filter").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        publish.push($(this).val());
        //I am checked
    }else{
        //I'm not checked
        publish.splice(publish.indexOf($(this).val()), 1)
    }
    filterProduct();
});
```

**CategoryController.php**

```
public function filter(Request $request)
{
    $products = Product::query();

    if($request->has('publish') && $request->publish === 1) {
        $products->where('published', 1);
    }

    $products = $products->get();

    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'data' => $products,
    ]);
}
```

I added the following line in `CategoryController`

```
dd($request->publish);
```

When I clicked `Yes` I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bVz7.png) display in the network tab.

And When I clicked `No` I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9VpV.png) display in the network tab.

And I'm not sure how to solve it. So I hope someone can help me. I have very little experience with AJAX that's why I'm asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

wasn't sure what you're trying to achieve but based on your example I assume you only want to send all only the radio options where yes is selected?

```js
var publish = []
$(".published_filter").change(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('id') === 'yes') {
    publish.push($(this).is(':checked'));
    //I am checked
  } else {
    //I'm not checked
    publish.splice(publish.indexOf($(this).is(':checked')), 1)
  }
  console.log(publish)
  // filterProduct();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card mb-3">
  <div class="card-header">{{ __('Published') }}</div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input published_filter" type="radio" name="published" id="yes">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="yes">
                Yes
            </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input published_filter" type="radio" name="published" id="no">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="no">
                No
            </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Not. I want you to show me products that are equal to published = 1

Comment: if {{ __('Published') }} is where the published  value is and you want to filer on that then this should give you the value within that div "($(this).parentsUntil(".card-header").find(".card-header").text()"   when added inside "$(".published_filter").change(function() {" you can use that to then filter, or are you trying to filter the json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'data' => $products,
    ]);
jquery side ?

Comment: I want to filter based on JSON.

Comment: My `filterProduct` works great and only I want to click on the radio to work, which doesn't work.

Comment: ah i think i get it now sorry for the slow-up take so the product array is coming from the json response? and that's the bit you want to filter, are you able to post the json response object it would help to know what it looks like to know how best to filter it, it should just come downt to matching whats in the json object to the radio buttons  using https://api.jquery.com/filter/